# in_array ignores 000 after decimal

Tags: php

```
$arr = array(2.1,3.1);

if(in_array(2.1000,$arr))
   echo "yes";
else
   echo "no";
```

I want it should show "No" but it ignores 0's after decimal point.

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes around `2.1000`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is `(string)$arr[0] == '2.1000'`. The only problem is that when using a floating number in PHP it's going to "remove" the leading and trailing zeros, therefore they are always going not to be zeros unless you store them as strings initially or if you keep track of the leading and trailing zeros in another array.

Answer (score 0):

`2.1` will always equal `2.1000`, since they represent the same value (they just differ in *representation*, which is lost as soon as PHP parses the number). You'll have to store at least one value as a string `'2.1000'` to get this sort of "representation comparison".

Answer (score 0):

The internal floating point representation of the number `2.1000` is exactly the same as `2.1`, so the code can't tell the difference.

We must always be aware of the difference between the *internal representation* of numeric value, and the representation we use in code or see in output.